# Quantifying spatial correlations for independent images

Tags: correlation, python, spatial, image-processing, methodology

I have a series of maps (100x100 pixels each) and for each map, each pixel is labeled according to what is located there (currently values are in RGB, where each color denotes a different substrate).  I'm looking for a method to compare the maps, to quantify the extent of overlap, and determine if/when its statistically different from a baseline level. This would be done for each of the substrates.

For example, in the image below, there are 3 colors (blue, red, yellow).  Blue makes up 50% of the map, yellow and red each make up 25%.  When we compare the two maps, we see that blue is in the same location for 1 of the 2 pixels (upper left corner).  Red does not overlap, and yellow perfectly overlaps (lower right-hand corner in both maps).

In this example, we have 100% overlap for yellow, 0% for red, 50% for blue. But it seems like one should account for the baseline amount of each color (i.e. blue makes up 50% of the image, so having some overlap would be expected). Similarly, yellow makes up a smaller proportion of the image, and so the overlap is more unexpected (the real maps are bigger).

In the real data, we have up to 12 different colors, and there are undefined areas (to be ignored). The paired maps have roughly the same amount of each color, but there's also some noise in the pixel locations (i.e. the maps are not perfect, if there's a cluster of blue in one location, could be offset by a couple pixels in the other map).

Any ideas on what would be a good method for showing, statistically, if/when the overlap in two maps is non-random?  This would be done for each color, because we're interested in seeing if some colors are more likely to show overlap than others.

If possible, would be nice to do in python.

[image: two hypothetical maps]

Comment: Does the orientation matter? Like, you could turn the left image by ninety degrees, which would result in the two blue squares lining up. If the orientation is important, you could try flattening the images (all pixel of one image make up a vector) and then compute the cosine similarity. If the error in the maps is small, this should give you an idea of what images are similar.

Comment: The orientation does matter, so rotating the image 90 degrees wouldn't work.

Comment: Then I would try a simple distance or similarity measure. And see if that is good enough for your case

Comment: When you say similarity measure, what did you have in mind?  Not sure if distance would really solve the issue, because you can still calculate a distance between regions that have no overlap.

Comment: For example the cosine similarity would work. And while you are correct, that is is not perfect. I would assume that image swith more overlap have a higher similarity than the ones who have less overlap. Calculating the cosine similairty is quite fast., so even if you are not happy with the results you would ot waste a lot of resources on it